# rails sha1 hash for route to object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to my controller in my app to not just respond to the id of the object sent from it's route, but actually a sha1 hash, i've generated using `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest`.

So instead of:

```
/client/invoice/1
```

I want the url to be something like:

```
/client/invoice/0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the URL for an object in Rails generally involves two things:

First, change relevant controller actions to use a finder that works the way you want it to. In your case you probably want to write a custom finder in your Invoice model, like:

```
def self.find_by_id_or_sha1(id)
  Invoice.find_by_id(id) || Invoice.find_by_sha1(id)
end
```

and then use `Invoice.find_by_id_or_sha1(params[:id])` in your controller actions (show, edit, update, destroy).

Second, change generated URLs to follow your new design (if desired). So, if you want `link_to("Jan 1, 2010", @invoice)` to go to `/client/invoice/0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0`, override the default `to_param` method in your Invoice model. For example:

```
def to_param
  sha1
end
```

(That assumes your invoice's SHA1 hash is stored in the sha1 attribute.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Invoice.first(:conditions=>["SHA(id) = ?",params[:id]])
```

Comment: not really a totally solution, but nice idea! +1, also welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Unsecure. Should include a salt otherwise anyone can just do a SHA(int) to find the URL for each invoice.